# Inserting data from SQL Server to Postgres - UTF8 0x00 error

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, pyspark, utf-8

I am using PySpark to read data from SQL Server and write it to a Postgres DB on AWS.

The `INSERT` to Postgres fails with this error

> ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

I have been searching for a fix but no luck. That statements I have used to find char(0) say there are none in any of the columns. I'm using this

```
cast(ExportName AS varchar) like '%' + char(0) +'%'
```

REPLACE doesn't work.

I tried changing the encoding in pyspark script with

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

but still getting the error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the full pyspark code

```
# pyspark --jars /deployment/mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre8.jar,/deployment/postgresql-42.2.11.jar --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 8 --executor-memory 16g
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local").setAppName("My app")
 
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

ms_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://hostname;instanceName=instance;databaseName=database;"
ms_user = "username"
ms_password  = "password"
mssql_query = ''' (SELECT *
                FROM DBO.TBL_SENSORS
                WHERE TYPE IN ('S','C')) query'''
 
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", ms_url) \
    .option("dbtable", mssql_query) \
    .option("user", ms_user) \
    .option("password", ms_password) \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()

pg_url = "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/database"
pg_user = "pg_username"
pg_password = "pg_password"
pg_table = "SCO.TBL_SENSORS"

jdbcDF.write.format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .option("url", pg_url)\
    .option("user", pg_user) \
    .option("password", pg_password) \
    .option("dbtable", pg_table) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

Comment: Best guess is the MSSQL encoding is not UTF8 and you will need to something along the lines of the examples here [Client encoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html#id-1.6.10.5.7). To get a more specific solution you will need to provide more specific information: 1) The encoding in the MSSQL database 2) The actual code you are using in PySpark.

Comment: Thanks - I'll check the encoding, I added the full pyspark script